# How to find a root of this crash in the UIKit somewhere?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, crashlytics

I have been receiving this kind of crash from Crashlytics. It happens randomly anytime and its unreproducible. I have got a stack trace that points to an error of NaN in the frame property. but I can't find anything like this in my code also none of the thread contains code written by me, so its very hard to find the cause of this.

I am attaching the stack trace of the same.

```
`Fatal Exception: CALayerInvalidGeometry(CALayer position contains NaN: [nan 8])
0  CoreFoundation                 0x191066fe0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18fac8538 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x191066f28 -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  QuartzCore                     0x194375acc CA::Layer::set_position(CA::Vec2<double> const&, bool)
4  QuartzCore                     0x194375c48 -[CALayer setPosition:]
5  QuartzCore                     0x194376198 -[CALayer setFrame:]
6  UIKit                          0x1977de83c __26-[_UILabelLayer setFrame:]_block_invoke
7  UIKit                          0x1977de6cc -[_UILabelLayer _setFrameOrBounds:settingAction:]
8  UIKit                          0x1977de7e8 -[_UILabelLayer setFrame:]
9  UIKit                          0x19718a7a8 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:]
10 UIKit                          0x19719a068 -[UILabel setFrame:]
11 UIKit                          0x19719b3bc -[UIView(Geometry) sizeToFit]
12 UIKit                          0x1972dc6ac -[UISegment _positionInfo]
13 UIKit                          0x19753b7d4 -[UISegment layoutSubviews]
14 UIKit                          0x19718e07c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
15 QuartzCore                     0x19437e274 -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
16 QuartzCore                     0x194372de8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
17 QuartzCore                     0x194372ca8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
18 QuartzCore                     0x1942ee34c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
19 QuartzCore                     0x1943153ac CA::Transaction::commit()
20 UIKit                          0x1973ecbd8 _UIWindowUpdateVisibleContextOrder
21 UIKit                          0x1973ec9e8 +[UIWindow _prepareWindowsPassingTestForAppResume:]
22 UIKit                          0x1974285b0 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]
23 UIKit                          0x197427ef8 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationLifecycleEventWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]
24 UIKit                          0x1974134a8 __70-[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
25 UIKit                          0x197413124 -[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]
26 UIKit                          0x19774d7c8 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:]
27 FrontBoardServices             0x192be222c __80-[FBSSceneImpl updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.376
28 FrontBoardServices             0x192c0f884 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
29 FrontBoardServices             0x192c0f6f0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext]
30 FrontBoardServices             0x192c0faa0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource]
31 CoreFoundation                 0x19101542c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
32 CoreFoundation                 0x191014d9c __CFRunLoopDoSources0
33 CoreFoundation                 0x1910129a8 __CFRunLoopRun
34 CoreFoundation                 0x190f42da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
35 GraphicsServices               0x1929ac074 GSEventRunModal
36 UIKit                          0x1971f6058 UIApplicationMain
37 XXXXXXXX                       0x1000550ac main (main.m:14)
38 libdyld.dylib                  0x18ff5159c start
`
```

The code for tweaking a UISegmentControl is as below, it's very old code. It was working fine until now.

```
    for (id segment in [SegmentControl subviews]) 
    {
        for (id label in [segment subviews]) 
        {
            if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
            {
                //hear u add any of delegate function to increase the height and other label functionality in this 
                [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
//                [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11]];
                [(UILabel *)label setNumberOfLines:2];
                //to adjust the label size manually with respect to text use below code
                [(UILabel *)label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
                CGRect frame = [(UILabel *)label frame];
                frame.size = [(UIView *)segment frame].size; 
                frame.size.width = (SegmentControl.frame.size.width / [[[[self currentField] definition] listOfValues] count]) - 4;
                frame.origin.x = 2;
                frame.origin.y = 0;

                [(UILabel *)label setFrame:frame];
            }
        }           
    }
```

And also my app never crashes while executing this code specifically. And also `listOfValues` is never empty. I am sure of that.

Comment: Do you calculate a frame somewhere? Perhaps you're dividing by zero.

Comment: Your app is trying to layout `UISegmentedControl` when resuming the app and crashes due to invalid position. It seems you are doing something wrong with your view hierarchy. It's possible your view hierarchy was already in a bad state before the crash. Search you console for warnings.

Comment: check in this class `FrontBoardServices`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik 'FrontBoardServices' is an internal class. its not in my code.

Comment: @Sulthan even I thought the same seeing UISegment in the stack trace, but I didn't find anything related to the UISegment class in the documentation. its internal stuff. although I have tried to change the size of the UISegmentedControl's labels in the app but this stack trace is not pointing to that I will update the answer with that tweak code.

Answer (score 1):

Run analyzer: Product -> Analyze.
It will show you bad places in code.
Looks like you have division by zero.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the NaN issue, you have divided something by nil. As far as I see, you have divining operation only here, check the denominator for different cases and you will find the solution:

frame.size.width = (SegmentControl.frame.size.width / [[[[self currentField] definition] listOfValues] count]) - 4;